# How to scrape plaintext from multiple links off of one website?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as py
import json
import csv
import re
import urllib.request
sauce = 
urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls003073623/").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')
soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('^/title/'))
```

I am trying to scrape multiple links off of a website (about 500) and I don't want to manually input each and every URL, how do I go about scraping this?

Answer (score 0):

### With BeautifulSoup

If I understand it right, you are trying to obtain a list containing **a part** of all the links on a given website. There is an [example](https://pythonspot.com/extract-links-from-webpage-beautifulsoup/) on BeautifulSoup's documentation that shows exactly how to do that:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls003073623/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
ids = []

for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
    ids.append(link.get('href').split("/")[4])

print(ids)
```

### With Selenium

For reference, and since it doesn't seem like the question is limited to only BeautifulSoup, here's how we would do the same using Selenium, a very popular alternative.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls003073623/")

ids = []
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")

for elem in elems:
    ids.append(elem.get_attribute("href").split("/")[4])

print(ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry if my question was vague but what I'm trying to do is get a list that contains the "tt0068646" from all of the links in the website that look like this: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/?ref_=ttls_li_tt

Comment: @ZackSturgeon your question completely skips over this fact, please edit your question

Comment: In that case it’s a matter of splitting the url by `/` and keeping the fifth element. I updated my answer to reflect this, you should update your question to reflect the new problem specification.